# How to get nodes that do not belong to a particular user role

Tags: 8, nodes, entities, database

I am getting custom entity nodes using entity queries like below:

```
  $query= $this->entity_query->get('order_entity')
      ->condition('external_id', $data['external_id']);

  $order_nids2 = $query->execute();
```

I am trying to put a condition where I can get nodes which do not belong to a particular user role. How can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What do you mean by _custom entity nodes_? If it's a custom entity, it's not a node; if it's a node, it's not a custom entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes are only associated with author's nids (not user roles)

Thus you should do a query first to get the userids that match your selected user roles.  Then use that array to filter out nodes with authors that belong to those user ids.